# Header size enlarge when i click on hamburger menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i open my website in mobile and click on hamburger menu. the header size enlarge. It looks like logo zoom out. I am facing this issue because I want to have a sticky header on my site.

following is the CSS i wrote for sticky header:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    header {
        top: 0px;
        position: fixed !important;
    }
}
```

Site URL: http://gomodemo.se/port73/

Can someone help me to fix the header zooming effect.

Comment: Try removing `padding: 89px 0;` from `#mobile-advanced`

Comment: I have removed the #mobile-advanced padding

Comment: No still in mobile device, The header zoom out on click of hamburgar menu